# worst and average complexity of algorithm?

Tags: performance, algorithm, complexity-theory

Input is a list L of a number of 1's (or none) followed by a number of 2's (or none). The algorithm below finds the number of 1's. For average case, assume L has equal chance of containing a 1.

```
A(L):
     n=L.length
     m=sqrt(n)
     p=m-1
     while p<n and L[p]=1
         p+=m
     p-=m+1
     while p<n and L[p]=1
         p+=1
     return p
```

Comment: What do you think? What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved O(log2(n)), simply by bisecting the list.

As for the algorithm you have here, its complexity is about O(2sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 0):

This loop can only be executed sqrt(n) times before p is reaching n.

```
while p<n and L[p]=1
     p+=m
 p-=m+1
```

The same is true for this loop since the difference between p and n is less then sqrt(n)

```
 while p<n and L[p]=1
     p+=1
 return p
```

As a result your complexity is O(sqrt(n)) in average and worst case.

Comment: @Peter The factor of 2 can be ignored in the O-notation of O(2sqrt(n))

Comment: I would say that the average case is not better than the worst case if we stick to the O-notation.